# Passing Parameter through document,getElementById() in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

Here's a class for displaying a table in react which a column consisting of delete icon. I'm trying to pass id of row as a parameter but it seems like null is passed as on execution I'm getting following error:

```
Cannot read property 'style' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at FolderDetails.delrow (http://localhost:6006/main.3cce3b0c8eebe2bc56b3.bundle.js:1384:9)
    at FolderDetails.render (http://localhost:6006/main.3cce3b0c8eebe2bc56b3.bundle.js:1395:23)
    at finishClassComponent (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.3cce3b0c8eebe2bc56b3.bundle.js:232974:31)
    at updateClassComponent (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.3cce3b0c8eebe2bc56b3.bundle.js:232929:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.3cce3b0c8eebe2bc56b3.bundle.js:233877:16)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.3cce3b0c8eebe2bc56b3.bundle.js:237545:12)
    at workLoop (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.3cce3b0c8eebe2bc56b3.bundle.js:237585:24)
    at renderRoot (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.3cce3b0c8eebe2bc56b3.bundle.js:237668:7)
    at performWorkOnRoot (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.3cce3b0c8eebe2bc56b3.bundle.js:238575:7)
    at performWork (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.3cce3b0c8eebe2bc56b3.bundle.js:238487:7)
```

I've tried all the combinations I could. But it doesn't seem to work. Can it really be done using document.getElementById() or any any other method exists in React?

The code:

```
class FolderDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.delrow = this.delrow.bind(this);
  }

  delrow(id) {
    document.getElementById({id}).style.display="none";
  }
  
  render() { 
    return (
  <div>
      <h2>Tables</h2>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Option</th><th>Description</th><th></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="1">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>path to data files to supply the data that will be passed into templates.</td>
        <IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'Delete' }} onClick={this.delrow("1")}/>
      </tr>
      <tr id="2">
        <td>engine</td>
        <td>engine to be used for processing templates. Handlebars is the default.</td>
        <IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'Delete' }} onClick={this.delrow("2")}/>
      </tr>
      <tr id="3">
        <td>ext</td>
        <td>extension to be used for dest files.</td>
        <IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'Delete' }} onClick={this.delrow("3")}/>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the function delrow is pure js, so in the code segment,

```
document.getElementById({id}).style.display="none";
```

you need not to use curly braces i.e use

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
```

we usualy use curly braces to represent js objects in jsx, which is not the case here

EDIT:-

Very sorry I didnt considered your all code.
But yes, the problem is you are calling the function but u must just pass it like a object or something.

```
<IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'Delete' }} onClick={this.delrow("1")}/>
```

must be as

```
<IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'Delete' }} onClick={this.delrow}/>
```

and change the function code as:

```
delrow(event) {
    var ele = event.target;
    ele.style.display="none";
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the correction but unfortunately same error persists: